# How can I display the objects of an array from an API?

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have an array with 100 objects from an [API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts), every object has an "user Id" key.
The array is something like:

```
[{  "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  }, etc ]
```

How can I display all the objects in console? After this I have to search in array for a specific userId introduced by the user in the main page of application, I use express, body-parser, https from node.js.

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){
  var userId = req.body.userId;
  console.log(userId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**How can I show all the objects in console?**

Assuming that you receive the array a variable name `apiResults`

```
console.log(apiResults) //or
console.log(JSON.stringify(apiResults))
```

**I have to search in array for a specific userId..?**

Use the `Array.protype.some` method to return a specific item from an array

```
var specificUser = apiResults.some(item => item.userId === preferedUser);
```

Comment: I've used the node_fetch package, how can I save the array in apiResults variable? I am new in API working.

Comment: Please follow this documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch